# How to create the EAR directory structure for App Engine projects automatically in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I know Google Plugin for Eclipse can create the web-archive (WAR) structure automatically for App Engine projects. If there are more than one modules in my project, how can I get eclipse to create the enterprise archive (EAR) structure, ie., WAR directories for all modules and application.xml, app-engine-application.xml and other default files?

Many thanks for any help! I have not found guidance on this process anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine has added support for EAR module development since SDK 1.8.2. You will have to create a new 'Enterprise Application Project' under Java EE in Eclipse and set Google App Engine as your target run time.

You can find more information at:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/webtoolsplatform#enterprise_application_ear

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Is there any support for modifying existing projects with just one module or would we have to update those manually?

Comment: Can't we have this support from the Google Plugin for Eclipse?